# Why adding additional outlier types reduces detectability?

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I've started my experience with package `tsoutliers` and I don't understand why when adding additional types of outliers to detect, I get fewer outliers in result.

Let's say following

```
tso(y=ts, types = c("TC", "AO", "LS"))
```

provides me with 6 different outliers. On the other hand

```
tso(y=ts, types = c("TC", "AO", "LS", "IO", "SLS"))
```

gives only 4 out of those previously detected and no new outliers.

I've read the documentation and I didn't find anything leading to the answer.